# ThreadPoolExecutor not being fully loaded

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have some experience with java.util.concurrent, but I don't know how to debug this issue.

I have a thread pool with max of 50 threads, I have a queue of execution of 500, and with a loop a submit jobs to that thread pool, in a way that when a job is done it come back to the queue again to be executed again. I have in a cycle 1000 jobs to execute, so the queue is always fully filled.

I'm instantiating the thread pool with that.

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(50, 
    50,
    0L, 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(500),
    Executors.defaultThreadFactory())
```

The issue is that always there are about 30 threads in execution, and not 50 as I expect.

Why?

Tks.

Comment: Looks like   30 threads are good enough to process your jobs.

Comment: It's not, the average duration of the job is 15 minutes, and at the begining 1000 jobs are submitted at the same time.

Comment: Any chance you can narrow this down to an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can run? A working demo will likely allow us to explain exactly what's going on.

Comment: Also, how exactly are you determining that there are 30 threads executing?

Comment: dimo, the very first step of the process that the threads execute is mark the job as being executed at the database, so the number of executing job at the same time is determined by a query.